# Bug with new questions with activity feature

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-questions

I left the window open for sometime, and the questions with new activity message appeared.

I clicked it and the new question(s) faded in as expected.

Now, if i click any other question (but not anywhere that would cause me to go to that question), for example in the blank space just to the right of the question's tags, the new question fades in each time i click.

I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome.

Comment: It'll take a while to reproduce :)

Comment: I can't reproduce this, can you explain further what "if i click any other question (not anywhere that would cause me to go to that question)" means?

Comment: @NickCraver: Although it's been sorted, i've edited to hopefully be a little clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was in fact a bug, the click handler was wired up to more than it should have been.  This will be fixed in our next build.