# "Questions with New Activity" not on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, live-refresh

In a similar vein to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123652/175248), I'm having an issue with the "new questions with activity" feature on SO.  It works fine on any other Stack Exchange site.

I've left the window open for about 20 minutes now, and it doesn't update the list with any interesting questions with activity.  I even threw in the C# tag into my favorites to make sure that it wasn't just my favorite tags.

I'm using the latest version of Chrome on Xubuntu Linux.

Comment: Think about how about many new questions SO gets every minute... That bar will never go away for more than a few seconds...

Comment: @Mysticial:  You may have a point there.  Maybe I"m unfamiliar with how it works; I don't have an account on the other SE sites I've seen it on, so I wouldn't know how the questions would be quantified - would they be what I'm interested in?  What's just been posted?  Etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature was intentionally left off of StackOverflow's homepage:

- [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)
- [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox)

The reason is that given the sheer amount of traffic on SO, that bar will never go away for more than a few seconds. So it's been restricted only to the tag listings.

Comment: Oh!  Well that makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) it was intentionally done, but partially considered:

> We have also enabled updates on the questions page for the newest and
>   active tabs for all sites **except Stack Overflow**. If you open a
>   browser to these tabs you will receive instant notifications when new
>   questions are asked or answered.
>
> Stack Overflow has a massive amount of activity so we have decided to
>   limit this feature to tags only. Both the "newest" and "active" tab
>   will have updates after first selecting a tag or tag combination.

So, if you select a tag or a tag combination, you will have that "questions with new activity" shown (just in the "newest" and "active" tab).